# Shouldn't the definition of the Frechet derivative not require $a$ to be a limit point?

Tags: limits, derivatives, definition, frechet-derivative

Throughout this section we assume $V$ and $W$ are normed vector spaces, with $V'$ an open subset of $V$ and $f$ a function defined $V'\to W.$

*Definition:* The function $f:V'\to W$ is ***differentiable at*** $a\in V'\subseteq V$ if there exists a continuous and linear transformation $L:V\rightarrow W$ such that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)|_W}{|h|_V}=0.$$
The linear transformation $L$ is called the ***derivative of $f$ at*** $a$ and it's denoted by
$$f'_a = f'(a) = Df(a) = D_a f.$$

---

**My question:** for the limit above to be well defined we must have that $0$ is a limit point of the function
$$h\mapsto \frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)|_W}{|h|_V}$$
which is -I believe- equivalent to $a$ being a limit point of $V'$. **Should the definition not require that $a$ to be a limit point of $V'$ then?**

Comment: It is an element of an open set. That's better than merely being a limit point.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I'm sorry if I'm confused, but can't an isolated point be a member of an open set?

Comment: What do open sets in a normed space look like?

Comment: @peek-a-boo on the one hand, I don't know :p, but on the other hand the Fréchet derivative is defined between normed (not necessarily complete) vector spaces.

Comment: If you don't know that's where you should start. You can't answer anything without definitions, so look them up. Do you know about $\Bbb{R}^2$? What about $\Bbb{R}$? Is the interval $(0,2)$ an open set? What kind of point is $0$? What about 2? What about 1? Or perhaps my question seemed too broad: I mean there is a very obvious class of sets which generate the topology in a normed space (in my previous comment I said 'Banach' out of habit. Many of the introductory theorems don't need completeness, but in any actual application you'll want completeness otherwise analysis is next to impossible).

Comment: @peek-a-boo well, I have not studied Banach or Normed Spaces by themselves; what I'm currently doing is going through Spivak's _Calculus on Manifolds_ and generalizing the results as much as possible. The definition of the Fréchet derivative -In Wikipedia- is the same as the one I wrote. This all being said, am I right in thinking that -if the Fréchet derivative is defined between arbitrary normed spaces-, then $a$ should be required to be a limit point of $V'$?

Comment: You've literally not answered my 3 simple example prompts which will tell you that 'if a is an element of an open set in a normed space, then it is not isolated; it lies inside a ball of positive radius'. And even more directly, if you're an element of an open set in a normed space (or metric space for that matter), you're automatically a limit point. If you're going through Spivak, then you should already have the answers to my 3 prompts at the least (btw almost every result in chapter 2 there generalizes verbatim; see Loomis and Sternberg, or Henri Cartan's differential calculus).

Comment: @peek-a-boo oh. Well I do know $I=(0,2)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, that $0$ and $2$ are limit points of $I$ and $1$ an interior (and limit) point of it. This is merely an example though. Could you please point me to some text or at least a proof that explains why any element of an open set in a NVS is a limit point?

Comment: @peek-a-boo while it is true that "if $a$ is an element of an open set in a normed space, then it is not isolated; it lies inside a ball of positive radius", what is not obvious to me is that said ball _must_ contain a point different from $a$ itself.

Comment: @peek-a-boo the proof would generalize instantly if I knew why any open ball centered at $a$ must contain a point different than $a$ itself, but again, it's not clear why that is always the case in an NVS.

Comment: (ignore my paranthetical remark about metric spaces above). Fine: here's the proof. If $a$ lies in a ball and $b$ is any other vector, then for any sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, the point $a+\epsilon (b-a)$ also lies in the ball. Draw a picture. Of course we're assuming the vector space is not zero dimensional, so there exists atleast one other point.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ah I see. Thank you (: